# Assigning value in JSON inside the same JSON

Tags: json

Is there a way that this is possible?

```
  {
    id: "1",
    firstName: "John",
    middleName: "Smith",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  },
```

I want to set the value of fullName to be the combination of firstName and lastName.

Comment: no, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you are using. You could, in Javascript, make that in two separate steps:

1. create the object with the data you without the fullName:

```js
let person = {
    id: "1",
    firstName: "John",
    middleName: "Smith",
    lastName: "Doe",
  };
```

2. And then create the attribute you want using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
person = {...person, fullName: `${person.firstName} ${candidates[0].lastName}`};
```

Maybe that helps!